# RewriteMap rnd in .htaccess symfony2

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, rewritemap

I'm currently trying to do a simple random load balancing using 2 servers with symfony2.

In the /web .htaccess file, I have tried a lot of combinations, but result is always blank and I do not see a way to debug. What could help ?

.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap servers rnd:/map.txt

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,PT]
</IfModule>
```

The map.txt is in the /web folder too.
The problem occurs when I add the line `RewriteMap servers rnd:/map.txt`

Comment: Pay attention to “Context”: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Comment: Thanks, putting RewriteMap in the .htaccess file did the trick.